Wireshark didn't display the IP addresses and port numbers of the server and client, despite successful message exchange. How to fix this issue
set up UDP client-server communication and installed Wireshark on Ubuntu to monitor packet capture . However, Wireshark didn't display the IP addresses and port numbers of the server and client, despite successful message exchange. How to fix this issue
Solution to fix this issue

If communication works but you were not able to capture anything then you did the capturing wrong. What exactly you did wrong is not clear since it is not clear how did tried to capture in the first place and what your setup is.

Did you select the right interface/capture target in Wireshark?
Your descriptions sounds like you saw no packets in a running Wireshark while the transmission you wanted to watch was successful.
For a quick control you could alternatively use something like "tcpdump -i eth0 -w Test.pcap" to create a PCAP capture of the transmitting interface (in this example eth0) and open the generated file with Wireshark verify if data is really transmitted on the interface you expect.
